# Cloudflare and AWS - Intermittent 525 SSL Handshake

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, cloudflare

I'm getting an intermittent (approximately 0.01% of requests) 525 (SSL Handshake failed) between Cloudflare and our AWS EC2 Windows 2016 IIS, with Let's Encrypt CA installed using [win-acme](https://win-acme.com) running as Administrator. We're ReactJs front and .NET Framework 4.7.2 on the back.

### Things I've tried

- I've been through Cloudflare standard sources: [The Community Tip](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-525-ssl-handshake-failed/44256) and [Debug Docs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed#525error)
- I've raised a support ticket with Cloudflare, they told me "Connection Reset By Peer" during handshake.
- I've checked IIS logs, I can see the user interacting successfully but the IIS doesn't record any failure.
- IIS Failed Request Tracing is on but not showing anything (it's not getting as far as IIS).
- I have [SCHANNEL logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/enable-schannel-event-logging) switched to verbose: "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL" Value 7 - I only see [36880 (SSL negotiated successfully)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786445(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#event-id-36880-an-ssl-client-or-server-handshake-completed-successfully) status codes in the Event Viewer.
- 525 occurs irrespective of device, browser, OS, method or endpoint (both POST data and GET of images). All clients are in the UK region.
- Although most of the failures are against the API, we've also seen the Cloudflare error page on our automation.
- My CloudFlare SSL setup is Full(Strict), 1.2 and 1.3 (SSL 3, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are switched off in registry on server).
- We have all the ciphers available to TLS 1.2 installed on the server, with SNI support.
- Server CPU, Mem, disk I/O and network I/O are all low at the times of the 525.
- We do not have an Elastic Load Balancer, the server connects straight to the AWS Gateway.
- No other processes are happening at the time (no patching, cert renewal or release).
- We have rate limiting switched off.
- Request load is very low, the most recent 525 (this morning) we were at about 50 requests/min.
- I have a second domain set up without proxying, using an AWS Canary to hit the site every so often. As of 2021/06/09 I've no failures (too early to tell)

### Things I can't easily do

- Use the [Cloudflare Origin CA](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507-Managing-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-certificates) certificate - moving over requires a fair amount of infrastructure automation change as we have a large number of multi-level sub domains that will need to be specified individually.
- Whitelisting Cloudflare IP on AWS by adding Cloudflare IPs to the Security Group that joins the EC2 instance to the gateway. I'll need a [Lambda function](https://github.com/johnmccuk/cloudflare-ip-security-group-update) to keep the list up-to-date.

### Things I can't do

- Remove Proxying (and see if it goes away). CF provides our DDoS protection, I am unable to turn it off and retain our security accreditation.
- [Install Wireshark](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/intermittent-525-errors-with-cloudflare-nginx-displayed/204332/14?u=rob10) on the server - these happen extremely intermittently, I would be generating huge logs. I also have change management restrictions, so I can't install whatever I like on the production server.

Is there anything I'm missing? If I get a resolution, I'll post back here to help others.

[Companion Post on Cloudflare Community](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/intermittent-525-ssl/275060)

Comment: I assume because of some of the restriction it's not possible to setup another subdomain to test in parallel without affecting production traffic? E.g. A subdomain pointing to the same server with CF proxy off. That could really help show the actual error. Do you also have a load balancer that does SSL offloading?

Comment: @KedMardemootoo thanks for the thoughts - we don't have a load balancer. I like the idea of having a mirror'd domain that I can set up a test ping. You're right that it's not trivial but at this stage, it's a thing to try, so I'll give that a go. Many thanks.

Comment: I've set that up and am collecting data - no failures as yet but too early to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution tldr;

We use ESET File Security 7 on our servers and it was creating a temporary blacklist of IPs, which sometimes included Cloudflare ones. I added Cloudflare IPs to the [IDS exception](https://help.eset.com/efsw/7.0/en-US/idh_config_epfw_ids_exceptions.html).

### Detail

The Cloudflare support engineer (Andronicus - thank you!) found the problem to be intermittent from within Cloudflare and suggested looking for anything that would do a dynamic blocking of IPs - especially Cloudflare's. As all our traffic comes through Cloudflare, it might look like an attack and attackers hitting the domain endpoint would also have a Cloudflare IP.

I took that and did a lot more reading. We're on AWS EC2, so the technology they use is [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc), which is on by default and deals with flood rather than our low levels.

I then did a full inventory of the server. Went through every single app and Windows Firewall in detail. I have plenty of experience with Windows Firewall, so I could see that there was nothing misconfigured.

[ESET File Security](https://www.eset.com/uk/business/download/file-security-windows/) for Windows Server is a pretty good anti-virus - particularly for botnet intrusion detection. It also has a feature called Network Attack Protection (IDS) for scanning for suspicious network traffic. Part of that is a "temporary IP address blacklist". From ESET:

> View a list of IP addresses that have been detected as the source of attacks and added to the blacklist to block connections for a certain period of time. Shows IP address that have been locked.

IPs get added to the blacklist for a short period of time. By watching the blacklist (it doesn't keep logs) I spotted some familiar Cloudflare IPs popping up.

I've added the [Cloudflare IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/ips/) to the [IDS exception list](https://help.eset.com/efsw/7.0/en-US/idh_config_epfw_ids_exceptions.html) (it allows address ranges) and raised a ticket with ESET to ask them how I keep that list up to date as Cloudflare can't be expected to keep the full list of IPs static.

If that doesn't help you, check out my [full post on Cloudflare Community](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/intermittent-525-ssl/275060).